# Grid view - Using radiobutton for single choice and checkbox for multiple choice(Kind of Quiz Application)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

i have some questions in my sql table, where radiobutton and checkbox need to be used dynamically to display the questions and choices in a grid.
my sql data table

```
question_id(int) | choice1 | choice 2 | choice3 | choice4 | correctanswer.
```

The assumption made here is that if the correctanswer length is =
1 then it is radiobutton control type else if `correctanswer > 1` , then it is check box type. Based on this can some one please help me how to display these question in a grid with appropriate radiobutton and checkbox controls and get the checked answers onclicking submit button.

Answer (score 0):

in gridview row databound event you have to check correct answer length and based on it show or hide radio button or check box

you have to put both in same row but manage to view based on your condition
and same thing you have to do when you going for save result in database.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Before finding the control in row databound im not clear about how to bind the dataset values to the grid. I will be fetching the questions one by one and for each qid i will be getting a dataset value which has the question, choice, correct answer all in a single row. How to bind this to the grid ??@Naresh